# Errors while run project or build apk

Tags: java, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-size

i run android studion with 32b system an 2gb memory
when i clean/build project i found 0 error but when i run/build APK 
5 errors 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUdP.png)

Comment: Post the error message as text instead of a linked image.

Answer (score 1):

The error says invalid maximum heap size 4GB, but your system is only 2GB, so it exceeds the system memory. you need to configure the acceptable heap size.

You can set the maximum memory usage to 1GB, like `-Xmx1024`, restart your IDE and it should work

Comment: Please how can i set the memory usage